# How to speed up queries with index design for a certain table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

Forgive me I am very new to indexes and DB.
I have a table with such columns :

```
    date        timestamp without time zone,
    date_num                         bigint,
    value                  double precision,
    name                               text,
    market                             text,
    type                               text,
    UNIQUE(name,date_num)
```

This table is :

1. Barely updated, only once a day with a single new row per name.
2. Have 6-10 million rows
3. For column `name` have many rows each for a unique day of the year. For example the `name` 'companyA' have 1250 rows, each row has a unique date/date_num.
4. `date_num` is a timestamp in millisecond for a certain day of the year we use it for search, sometimes we use `date`.

One of the things we search is *"find names with the highest revenue between dates"*, which mean for a `name` = "companyA" we will calculate:

```
revenue = (`value` of companyA in 14/2/2022 - `value` of companyA in 14/2/2021)
```

We then need to find the best 50 `names` with the highest such revenue.

For some reason the task takes up to 13 seconds, and I'v seen others doing this in 1 second.

1. What indexes are reasonable for such scenario?
2. What indexes are good in case we need to find/calculate many variations of `date/name/value` like this ?

Here is a query that need to find revenue of all `names` of a certain `type`.
**This query is not ideal because it serves many types of queries and originally contains parameters to change the sql string per query**

```
        WITH BS AS (
        SELECT date_num, name, value,
        first_value(value) over (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY date_num) as o,
        first_value(value) over (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY date_num DESC) as c,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY date_num DESC) as rn
        FROM historical
        WHERE date_num >= 1609459200 AND date_num <= 1640995200 AND type = 'typeA'
        )
        SELECT name, date_num, CASE WHEN o=0 THEN null ELSE 100 * ( (c - o)/o ) END as out_return
        FROM BS
        WHERE BS.rn = 1
        ORDER BY out_return  DESC NULLS LAST
        LIMIT 50
```

PS- the `type` column has a certain value for 95% of the table, and only another value for the other 5%.

Comment: Please show us the complete query, then we can give you indexing advice.

Comment: Try to use only `name` and `date_num` columns in sql query select list, because you already have multicolumn index for them.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe i have added one of the queries, please know that i am aware it could be written different for sure, but this single query serve many types of solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can do to index this query is an index on `(type, date_num)`. Don't store timestamps as numbers.

Comment: thank you. Why not to store time stamps as numbers? it takes less space, and you can easily order numbers and query them. Can you explain ?

Comment: It does not take less space, and you can query and order timestamps just as easily. With numbers, you cannot benefit from date arithmetic - try to write `WHERE ts < current_timestamp - INTERVAL '1 month'` using numbers.

Comment: i understand. thanks a lot. I wonder if it affect speed of query.

Comment: Potentially yes, because your SQL expressions could become more complicated, which is slightly more expensive and harder to estimate for the optimizer.